# Change Kendo DatePicker Format on submit event

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

First of all, i'm new on MVC.

In my form, i'm using two datepickers as start and end time to display a report.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m))
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm taking date format with "tr-TR" culture like "dd/MM/yyyy". It supposed to be like this.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2013.3.1119/cultures/kendo.culture.tr-TR.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    kendo.culture('tr-TR');
    });
</script>
```

But i need to send date to controller in universal format like "yyyy/MM/dd". How can i change date format on submit event, before sending to server? 
My submit event below:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Criteria)

        <button class="btn-default" id="btnSearch" type="submit">Ara</button>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Kendo will send the date in as a DateTime object.  In the code behind, you simply convert that back to your culture.

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, it helped. But we can't rule server side every time. So we need to figure out it in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible approach would be to have both the client and the server side use the same culture all the times. More information on the matter can be found in the following help article:

- [Use the same culture on the server and client-side](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#use-the-same-culture-on-the-server-and-client-side)

Another option is to manually convert the value on form "submit" event or have custom model binder.